# How to tunnel VNC across multiple tunnels

Tags: networking, ssh, vnc

I have a unique problem where I'm trying to tunnel my VNC connection over SSH, however, I need to tunnel it through two systems to be able to access my VNC session remotely, because my company network only exposes a single port on one system, which isn't where I'm running VNC server.

My connection looks like this:
VNC Client --> ServerA (exposed ports) --> ServerB (VNC Server)

Constraints:
I cannot run VNC Server on ServerA due to policy
I cannot remote connect from outside the network to ServerB
I don't believe I can use VPN in this environmennt.

Comment: `ssh -L 5900:ServerB:5900 ServerA` then connect to localhost port 5900

Comment: Do I run this from ServerA or ServerB?

Comment: From the client, that's a plain [ssh port forward](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example). From your description, It doesn't look like you need more than one tunnel (as your title seems to imply).